# Bug when next tab with JsGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsgrid

why jsgrid presentation bug when i click at tab next? I try destroy e and raise the jsgrid and not solved.

```
 $('a[href="#prestador"]').on('show.bs.tab',function (e) {
        $("#nota_prestador").jsGrid("destroy");
        createGrid('nota_prestador',data,'CPF/CNPJ TOMADOR');
    });
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rendered in a hidden container (not opened tab in this case), js-grid cannot calculate size properly. 
So you have to call `refresh` on tab open event:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  $("#jsGrid").jsGrid("refresh");
});
```

Checkout the issue on the project GitHub page: https://github.com/tabalinas/jsgrid/issues/49